# How to drop Dataframe rows that start with a certain character string in the first column using column index

Tags: python, pandas

I am transposing a data frame where I do not have defined column names and then need to drop rows from the transposed table where a given rows value in the first column (index 0) starts with ‘zrx’. I am thinking something like this should work, but can’t seem to get it working:

```
df[~df[0].str.startswitg("zrx")]
```

Input data looks like this (no headers):

```
Index 0    Index 1
zrx456.       True
zrx567        false
abc234      True
Gfh123       False
nbv345       True
zrx456         False
zrx668        True
zrx789         True
```

My goal is to return this data frame with only the rows that start with zrx in column 0.

Comment: cant seem to get it workign.. what do you mean? whats the expected output vs what you are getting. Please provide details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the name of the first column, use

```
df[~df.Artist.str.startswith('zrx')]
```

If you do not know the name of the first column, use

```
df[~df.iloc[:,0].str.startswith('zrx')]
```

**input**

```
Artist  Album   Point
0   zrxAC1  A   1
1   AC2     B   2
2   zrxAC1  NaN     3
3   AC4     A   4
4   AC5     C   5
```

**Output**

```
Artist  Album   Point
1   AC2     B   2
3   AC4     A   4
4   AC5     C   5
```